# UNIX getfs(dev)

Tags: c, unix

I'm currently exploring the UNIX source code and I have trouble understanding a lot of it.

```
getfs(dev)
{
    register struct mount *p;
    register char *n1, *n2;

    for(p = &mount[0]; p < &mount[NMOUNT]; p++)
    if(p->m_bufp != NULL && p->m_dev == dev) {
        p = p->m_bufp->b_addr;
        n1 = p->s_nfree;
        n2 = p->s_ninode;
        if(n1 > 100 || n2 > 100) {
            prdev("bad count", dev);
            p->s_nfree = 0;
            p->s_ninode = 0;
        }
        return(p);
    }
    panic("no fs");
}
```

On the first line after the if statement, we try to access `p->m_bufp->b_addr`. How could possibly this happen, when `p->m_bufp` is an `int *`. And after that, we even assign all that to a variable with type `struct mount *`.

Can somebody explain what am I missing? [This](http://www.v6.cuzuco.com/v6.pdf) is a link to the full source code.

Thank you in advance! Have a nice day.

Comment: You are right, it can't work. Is there the *actual* source code somewhere which can be compiled?

Comment: Version 6 Unix™?  Talk about "old" — that predates 1978 (circa 1976).  C was a very different language back then.  The function definition line `getfs(dev)` is equivalent to `int getfs(int dev)`.   The `panic()` call won't return.  And it may have been from the era when structure members were in a single namespace across all structure types, rather than a separate namespace per structure type.  And dereferencing a pointer was fine as long as it was a pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I couldn't find one., but I'm looking forward to seeing it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you. I didn't know that. It was helpful. What do you think should I do? Is there any version of UNIX implemented with more modern C or it is a complete waste of time?

Comment: If you want to learn about the Unix kernel, you'd probably do better using a later version than V6 — you can find later versions (such as V7) on https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl, for example.  V7 Unix (what I started on, more or less) dates from 1978.  It uses a more modern version of C, one which was less lax about structure types, etc.  It is still K&R C (standard C was still a decade in the future), but hews closely to K&R 1st Edn (1978).  Any more recent version of Unix will be correspondingly closer to using standard C — it will be easier to understand (but still not easy).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you! Your information was very helpful.

Comment: Studying the kernel of one of the BSD variants would be another option. They are modern and not as bloated as the Linux kernel. Exploring the FreeBSD kernel and keeping a reference book like "Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System" aside would make the task easier.